# Zip document library using JSzip

Tags: javascript, jsom, download

How do I zip and download all the files (keeping the folder structure) from a document library using Jsom and jzip Library?

**Download multiple files then compress to one zip file using JSZip & JSZip-utils**
generate a single zip with multiple files with in multiple folder.from the code below I am able generate each zip for each folder with in a document library i want a single zip for all the folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**download all the files (keeping the folder structure) from a document library**

```
function Zip()
{
    deferreds = [];
    Fileurl=""; 
    filename="";
    array_Names=["abc","efg"];

    var Documentscxt = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.docs = Documentscxt.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    DocumentsallItems  = docs.getItems(query);
    Documentscxt .load(docs);
    Documentscxt .load(DocumentsallItems, 'Include(Title, ContentType,File,ID)');
    Documentscxt .executeQueryAsync(ZipDocument, onQueryFailed);                                                        
}

function ZipDocument()
{   
    var fileUrls="";
     var ListEnumerator = DocumentsallItems.getEnumerator();
        while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
            var _contentType = currentItem.get_contentType();
            for(var i=1;i<array_Names.length;i++)
            { 
          if (_contentType.get_name() != "Folder") {

                var File = currentItem.get_file();

                  if (File != null) {

                   fileUrls += File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '\n';
                   var url = fileUrls.split('/');
                   var folder = url[url.length - 2];   
                   if (folder == array_Names[i]) {
                   Fileurl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+'/sites/Documents/'+array_Names[i]+'/'+File.get_name();
                   filename=File.get_name();
                   var getFilesFromFolder =_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+'/sites/Documents/'+array_Names[i];

                        $.ajax({
                        url: getFilesFromFolder,
                        type: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            deferreds.push(deferredAddZip(Fileurl,filename, zip, 1, array_Names[i]));
                        },

                        error: function (error) 
                        {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
                        },

                        async: false
                    });
                   } 


                }   
            }
        }     
    }
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
                zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
                saveAs(content, "Document.zip");
                });
            });
}               
function deferredAddZip(url, filename, zip, isFolder, folderName) 
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); //for synchronous calls
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
            } else {
            if (isFolder != 1) {
                zip.file(filename, data, {
                    binary: true
                });
                } else {
                zip.folder(folderName).file(filename, data, {
                    binary: true
                });
            }
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });

    return deferred;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could consider the following solution:

- retrieve files collection via SharePoint JSOM API
- utilize [`getBinaryContent(path, callback)`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/documentation/api/getbinarycontent.html) from JSZipUtils to load
  file content by file url
- generate zip file

**Example**

```
loadFiles("Documents/2013",
        function(files) {
           var zip = new JSZip(); 
           zipFiles(zip,files,0,function(content){
               console.log('Done.');
               saveAs(content, "archive.zip"); 
           });
        },
        function(sender,args){
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }
    );
```

where

```
function zipFiles(zip,files,index,complete){
    index = index || 0;
    var curFile = files.get_item(index);
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(curFile.get_serverRelativeUrl(), function (err, data) {
       if(err) {
           throw err; // or handle the error
       }
       zip.file(curFile.get_name(), data, {binary:true}); 
       index++;
       if(index < files.get_count()) {
         zipFiles(zip,files,index,complete);
       }  
       else {
         zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
         .then(function(content) {
              complete(content);
         });  
       }       
    });
}


function loadFiles(folderUrl,success,error){
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
   var files = folder.get_files();
   ctx.load(files);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
           success(files);          
        },
        error); 
}
```

dependencies:

- [jszip.js](http://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/dist/jszip-utils.js)
- [jszip-utils.js](http://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/dist/jszip-utils.js)
- [FileSaver.js](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/vendor/FileSaver.js)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what version you are using from your question. Microsoft just announced this feature is coming with the modern SharePoint libraries in Office 365.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Download-OneDrive-files-and-folders-5c7397b7-19c7-4893-84fe-d02e8fa5df05?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 0):

I put this together that will let you zip an array of image urls.

https://jsfiddle.net/jaitsujin/zrdgsjht/

You can manage zip folder structure by modifying this line

```
filename = filename.replace(/[\/\*\|\:\<\>\?\"\\]/gi, '').replace("httpsi.imgur.com","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("AddZipIcon" );
function AddZipIcon() {
// for SP online
$(".ms-qcb-root ul li:nth-child(3)" ).each(function () {
$(this).first().before('<li class=" ms-qcb-item" >' +
'<a class=" ms-qcb-button ms-qcb-buttons-alignmentfix js-listview-qcbUploadButton js-callout-body js-qcb-button ms-qcb-glyph"  type=" button" ' +
'title=" Select files and download as a zip file" accesskey=" z"  onclick=" ConvertToZip()" ><span class=" ms-qcb-glyph ms-listview-glyph-withmargin ms-listview-sync-glyph ms-core-form-heading" ><img style=" height:20px;width:25px;"  src="https://" /></span><span class=" ms-qcb-glyph ">Zip</span></a></li>')
});
}
function CheckDownloadZip()
{
    return true;
}
function ConvertToZip()
{
 var seldocs = GetSelectedItemsDocsURLs();
 if(seldocs != null)
 {
 var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Creating Zip with selected files', 'Please wait while the files are added to zip...');

// alert("packaging..");
 DownloadPackage(seldocs);
 dialog.close(0);
 }
 
}
function GetSelectedItemsDocsURLs()
{
var tempurls = [];
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
if (items.length== 0) {
alert("Please select an item from the list" );
return null;
}
else
{
for (var i in items)
{
var getFileName = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists('"  + SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()+ "')/items("  + items[i].id + ")/?$select=EncodedAbsUrl" ;
$.ajax({
url: getFileName,
type: "GET" ,
headers: {
"accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
success: function (listData) {
tempurls.push(listData.d.EncodedAbsUrl);
// filename = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
},
error: function (error) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
},
async: false
});

}
}
 return tempurls;
}
function DownloadPackage(urls)
{
var filename = "selecteddocs";
//The function is called
compressed_img(urls, filename);

}
```